# How to copy a text word from html page to scripting variable onclick it

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want copy a word from a paragraph by just a single click on it to a scripting language variable to do some server side operation. How I can do it with php, javascript, Jquery, Ajax only.

My actual problem is that. I want develop a page from where if a user a single click on any word of that page that word copied to variable and that word searched in my database to do some operation.

But I am unable to copy word.

any help??? Forgive my English.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: just do $_SESSION['current_category'] = $_POST['category']; after the user clicks submit.

Comment: I dont see any HTML code for the Dropdown list so how are we supposed to help here

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: **WARNING**: You're putting `$_POST` data directly into your query without any checks or escaping whatsoever creating a giant [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). You **must** validate that the given parameter is a legitimate table name before using it, and even then you shouldn't put the user-supplied string in directly.